# Side Effects In Computed Property and Updating after it changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a page I want to update by using a nav drawer to go to my different groups I am querying from an API and writing that information to a datatable.  I keep getting unexepected side affect in returnurl computer property.  I'm not sure what I can do to fix this.  Also I'm trying to get the page to load again after the groupName has changed but I was unsuccessful with that so far as well.

Thanks

GroupList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="grouplist">
    <v-card-title>
      Swipe Report {{groupName}}
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="swipedata"
      :items-per-page="100"
      :search="search"
      loading
      loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
    ></v-data-table>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "GroupList",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      headers: [
        {
          text: "First Name",
          value: "firstname"
        },
        {
          text: "Las Name",
          value: "lastname"
        },
        {
          text: "Reader Location",
          value: "readerdesc"
        },
        {
          text: "Card Number",
          value: "cardnum"
        },
        {
          text: "Event Time",
          value: "eventtime"
        }
      ],
      groupName: this.$route.params.group,
      swipedata: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  computed: {
    returnurl() {
      return (this.returnurl =
        "http://localhost:5000/" + this.$route.params.group);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      axios
        .get(this.returnurl)
        .then(response => (this.swipedata = response.data));
    }
  },
  components: {}
};
</script>
```

Route:

```
 {
    path: "/groups/:group",
    component: GroupList,
  },
```

Links in are in following format:
http://localhost:5000/groups/Action
http://localhost:5000/groups/Salary
http://localhost:5000/groups/Hourly

With the GroupList view refreshing on each link, as it doesn't from the link.  I have to manually refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computed "returnurl" is formatted wrong.

A computed value will be whatever you return inside of it, you are not supposed to set it inside of the function, like you did with "returnurl = '...'".

Your computed should look like this:

```
returnurl(){
  return `http://localhost:5000/${this.$route.params.group}`;
}
```

Next, you want to be able to click a link, make the url change and then re-run your lifecycle hooks.

What is currently happening is intended behaviour by Vue, where it tries reusing the same component, expecting you to update the data.

A simply solution to rerun lifecycle hooks:
Add the "key" attribute to your router-view, like this:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">
```

This way, the key changes whenever anything changes in your url, and it should trigger a re-creation of the component.

You can see an example of that, made by LinusBorg [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/L7hscd8h/1528/)

This solution might be a bit too extreme in some cases, as this would trigger a recreation of all components in the router-view, which could be bad in bigger applications.

Another solution is to add a watcher to your $route, and call your init function inside of that, aswell as other changes you might want to make.

Here is an explanation of it from the [official vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: I need it to update as I am using the same component for all the groups reporting.  I have my links in the nav drawer and it will work after I manually hit refresh on the page but I need to be able to fire off the axios get when a link is selected and goes to the localhost:5000/groups/GROUPIDPASSEDIN

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you mean. You have a group of links. When you click a link, you want the url to change, with the groupId from the link. After you have clicked the link, you then want to fetch data from the api with the new id?

Comment: I have updated my original question with more information.  I want the GroupList view to update when each link is clicked from the nav drawer.

Comment: I understand now, I updated my answer, hope it helps.